# App crash when using UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput

Tags: ios, constraints, uialertview, uikeyboard

I have a very basic alert view

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Exit" message:@"Please enter the password." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
alertView.tag = 2;
alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;
[alertView show];
```

If I comment setting the `UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput` it works fine but if I left I get a crash when trying to show the alert view:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The layout constraints still need update after sending -updateConstraints to <_UIKeyboardLayoutAlignmentView: 0x155289c0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1558f510>>.
_UIKeyboardLayoutAlignmentView or one of its superclasses may have overridden -updateConstraints without calling super. Or, something may have dirtied layout constraints in the middle of updating them.  Both are programming errors.'
```

I'm positive that I'm not modifying the constraints of the `UIAlertView` though I do have a lot of constraints on the rest of the layout.

Why would simply having a text field on a `UIAlertView` cause the constraint crash?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. I have checked this and it works fine. Definitely app is crashing bacause of layout constraint. Try calling setNeedsUpdateConstraints after alert show. Something like this - [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637443/nsinteralinconsistencyexception-uikeyboardlayoutalignmentview refer this answer

Comment: @ViruMax That was actually my solution but I haven't had time to update this question, though I hadn't come across that link.